# convert a tuple of dict to networkx.Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a undirected graph : G  , it has nodes,edges and weights. I create it from a DataFrame use:

```
G = nx.Graph()
for key,value in df_couple.iterrows():   
    from_point = str(value[0])
    to_point = str(value[1])
    edgeweight = float(value[2])
    G.add_weighted_edges_from([(from_point, to_point, edgeweight)])
```

Then,I comput the shortest distance between all nodes,use:

```
dis = nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, cutoff=None, weight='weight')
```

I check the type of dis is 'generator',so I use:

```
In [23]:item = next(dis)

In [24]:item

Out[24]: 
('13537625459___1020004',
 {'13537625459___1020004': 0,
  '20-72-0D-39-01-6E___1020002': 0.40973195335611445,
  '20-72-0D-39-01-89___1020002': 0.24834431946516566,
  '20-72-0D-39-01-8A___1020002': 0.40973195335611445,
  '20-72-0D-39-01-8B___1020002': 0.40973195335611445,
  '20-72-0D-39-01-8D___1020002': 0.24026806227171532,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-96___1020002': 0.40973195335611445,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-A3___1020002': 0.40973195335611445,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-D4___1020002': 0.3179114489450109,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-DF___1020002': 0.23809674037229048,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-EF___1020002': 0.18307326555472847,
  '20-72-0D-39-02-F8___1020002': 0.23809674037229048})

In [25]:type(item)
Out[25]: tuple
```

I need convert the item(or dis) to format [nx.Graph]  for next step,so I use:

```
G_dis = nx.Graph(dict([item]))
```

Then I find just nodes,edges are success, but weight is not:

```
    In [28]:G_dis.nodes()
    Out[28]: NodeView(('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02EF___1020002', 
    '20-72-0D-39-02-DF___1020002', '20-72-0D-39-02-F8___1020002',
    '20-72-0D-39-01-8D___1020002', '20-72-0D-39-01-89___1020002', 
    '20-72-0D-39-02-D4___1020002', '20-72-0D-39-01-8A___1020002',
    '20-72-0D-39-01-8B___1020002', '20-72-0D-39-02-96___1020002', 
    '20-72-0D-39-02-A3___1020002', '20-72-0D-39-01-6E___1020002'))

    In [29]:G_dis.edges()
    Out[29]: EdgeView([('13537625459___1020004', '13537625459___1020004'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-EF___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-DF___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-F8___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-01-8D___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-01-89___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-D4___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-01-8A___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-01-8B___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-96___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-02-A3___1020002'), 
    ('13537625459___1020004', '20-72-0D-39-01-6E___1020002')])


  In[30]:G_dis.get_edge_data('13537625459___1020004','13537625459___1020004')
  Out[30]: {}
```

why the weight is {} ?, it should a float like'0.40973195335611445',but after convert it Become empty.

I try the nx.from_dict_of_dicts(d);nx.from_dict_of_lists(d) and other like functions in networkx,but useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your construction of `G_dis` is wrong. Try using tuples like when you created `G`.

This should work:

```
G_dis = nx.Graph()
for p1, d in nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, cutoff=None, weight='weight'):
    for p2, w in d.items():
        G_dis.add_weighted_edges_from([(p1, p2, w)])
```

Comment: That is worked！I can get the Graph with weight，but my Graph very huge，about 2,000,000 nodes and 1,500,000 edge. So this loop will cause memory error. How to optimization this loop in my situation，or another methods can avoid memory error when convert to Graph。

Comment: Imagine you have 100 nodes with 99 edges, one long line. After your procedure you will have 9900 (!) edges, as each node will have 99 edges to the others. For bigger graphs with sparse connections, you will at some point run out of memory. The better question is, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually,I want do fuzzy cluster analysis at the G_dis(do not know center point cluster for undirected Graph with weight , culstering by the weight as distance). So I thought first compute the shortest distance between all nodes as the tansitive closure of a-relation. Second convert it to nx.Graph. Third trans it to sparse matrix by scipy.sparse.last step use lambda to division nodes group.Case it is my first work for Graph cluster . the steps of work may be not very mature.